# Connecting Mac Book Pro 2017 to 2 Projectors via USB C

Tags: display, hdmi, projector

Just wondering can I connect my 13" MacBook Pro to 2 HDMI projectors? I would like to extend the displays ( 3 display, 1 laptop screen and 2 projector screen) instead of duplicating if that is possible.

I have purchased one of USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter from Apple, and if it can connect up to 2 additional extended displays, I will go for another one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Apple's Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=en_GB)  13” 2017 MacBook Pro is able to support 2 external displays.

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> - One display with 5120x2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colours
> - Up to two displays with 4096x2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colours
> - Up to two displays with 3840x2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colours

So, three total screens is a yes, four or more is a no. What’s undetermined is if you can run closed clamshell and have three distinct and active external displays and nothing on the internal display.

Comment: What a great collaboration for attributing this in a way that is not only clear, but hopefully durable for at least 3 to 5 years :)

Comment: The internal is never truly off. It always has a frame buffer allocated. The limitation is the number of memory apertures the GPU can handle...in this case 3.

Comment: Bill - I wasn’t aware of that detail. Want me to edit it in? Please feel free to edit my comment out or solidify what you know if I made things more uncertain than necessary.

Comment: Sure, Mike. Perhaps the clearest thing would be not mentioning clamshell mode though. Sometimes less is more. Apple phrases it as the built-in-display AND ( 1 5K or up to two 4K) monitors which also implies that the built-in is a fixed consumption resource.